# How to redirect 301 on the Digital Ocean App platform?

Tags: redirect, webserver, digital-ocean, http-status-code-301

How are 301 redirects made for websites on the Digital Ocean App platform?

I would like to redirect certain pages such as:

**domain.com/my-old-page/** redirects to **domain.com/my-new-page/**

I should mention that the content is being generated with Hugo static site generator.

Apparently, Netlify has a dedicated option with a .toml file, is there such a feature on DO's platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digital Ocean APP Platform doesn't **currently** support 301 redirects on static sites. They would only support default routing.